# Depend on external project from Kotlin Gradle DSL file build.gradle.kts

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

My Kotlin project has a dependency on a Java Maven project I cloned from githut and modified. Let's say it is in the folder `d:\code\otherproject`. How do I represent this in my build.gradle.kts file? Or do I have to move it all to a common directory tree and convert that project from Maven to Gradle too?

Here is the content of my build.gradle.kts so far:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    java
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.20"
}

group = "com.myproject"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { setUrl("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed") }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    testCompile("junit", "junit", "4.12")
    compile("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.6.20")
    compile("com.xenomachina:kotlin-argparser:2.0.7")
    compile("commons-io:commons-io:2.6")
    compile("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed:0.11.2")
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5")
    compile("com.zaxxer:HikariCP:3.2.0")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.1")
    compile("com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre")
    compile("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.3.0-alpha4")
    compile("ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.3.0-alpha4")
    compile("org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:1.17.1")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.6")
    compile("de.erichseifert.vectorgraphics2d:VectorGraphics2D:0.13")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.18")
    compile("org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3")
}

configure<JavaPluginConvention> {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```